# Overclocking of Ram on laptop

Tags: laptop, memory, graphics-card, motherboard

My laptop  have an 2GB and 4GB DDR3-1600MHz ram chip running at dual channel. Both Chips is of crucial technology. I have read in many posts that overclocking Ram can increase the performance of Integrated Graphics card as I have Intel HD Graphics on the motherboard "HP 1854". So is there any way or software to overclock ram because i want to increase my gaming performance

Comment: The firmware must support this type of functionality.  Your hardware's firmware does not.  Even if it did the amount of performance increase you can get from overclocking your memory on air cooling wouldn't be measurable difference.  To see sort of actual performance increase your talking about needing to double or triple the frequency which simply cannot be done on air.